# How can an immortal emperor's descendants affect the rate of population growth?

Tags: society, population

In the ancient nation of R'lyeth, a carpenter named Yeshuah Targeryean walked into a desert to prepare for his ministry. During this time, he was visited by a tentacled monstrosity who promised him worldly power and glory if only he would submit to him. After 40 days and 40 nights, the carpenter succumbed to his pathetic human weakness and sweared fealty to the creature. On that day, the carpenter died and was reborn as: The Temujin.

The Temujin began carving a bloody path throughout the country, conquering wherever he went until he became the undisputed ruler, taking many wives and concubines along the way. However, he couldn't ensure the complete loyalty of all 300 million inhabitants. Instead of genociding all who refused to bend the knee, he decided to have them replaced slowly over many generations. He plans to have every inhabitant have a genetic connection to his bloodline, thereby ensuring that everybody living in the country would be a descendent of his. His mortal children would slowly outnumber all people who weren't related, thereby exterminating them through population growth. In some future time, everyone would be able to trace their chromosomes back to him. For this to happen, there are two problems that need to be solved here:

1. There needs to be a way to encourage interbreeding  in order to eventually replace the entire country with The Temujin's descendents. However, a simple reward system wouldn't work, as not every child can be given a government job or some high position.
2. There also needs to be a minimum amount of children that need to be born each generation for this to happen, taking into account random events such as wars, famine, etc.

How can I accomplish these goals?

Comment: look up the Genghis khan effect.

Comment: After the first few sullen teenagers, R'lyeth might want to reconsider the assumed loyalty of offspring.

Comment: So... Jesus, with inexplicable GoT surname becomes immortal Genghis Khan, after he fails to resist "Temptation of Christ", except it's Cthulhu doing the tempting instead of g̶o̶o̶d̶ evil old Satan? That's quite a crossover you have in there.

Comment: @John Temujin IS Genghis Khan. Temujin was his given name, apparently meaning "blacksmith", Genghis Khan was a title. Khan means king, Genghis is an anglicised version of word made up specifically for him, probably meant to mean "just" or "true".

Comment: I had reason to do an analysis in college of how long it would take a fraternity of 50 brothers to use up a box of 1 million condoms. Alas, I don’t have it at hand anymore. But I remember it was about a decade. Remove the condoms and your answer is much the same.

Comment: (A) It probably wasn't necessary to offend well over 1 billion inhabitants of the earth with your backstory.  (B) This is basic mathematics but also nearly meaningless as it couldn't incorporate shifts in hereditary dominance (or subsidence) due to disease, war, starvation, inclement weather, bad luck, etc. (C) Why, exactly, can't you simply declare your desire to be true after a thousand years or so? What's time to an immortal? I'm not convinced an analysis would produce a more believable answer. What are the world rules involved here?

Comment: iam worry about the inevitable habsburg effect. heart as big as peppercorn,single testicle, short, lame, epileptic, senile and completely bald before 35, always on the verge of death but repeatedly baffling Christendom by continuing to live......

Comment: *"Minimum number of men":* why *men*, specifically? Don't daughters count? After all, women are much more likely to reproduce than men. (And it is all useless anyway; time will take care of it on its own; that is, after one or two thousand years everybody will have a connection to him automatically. Humans are very good at mixing up. All Europeans of European descent alive today are related to Charlemagne and all that. After sufficient generations, everybody is related to everybody.)

Comment: Extermination is the wrong word - interbreeding is better. Also, the gene set would need some observable trait to track to be able to tell who was related or not after a couple generations. Maybe he would need a special bureaucracy to track lineage and inherited traits to assure descent. Also some sort of system to reward descendants and encourage interbreeding. Maybe even based on generation - closer descendants can be ministers, great grand kids mayors and nobles. And of course any descendant can sleep with any unmarried woman they want...

Comment: @John Have you ever read the book Steppe by Piers Anthony? It does an interesting job of presenting the rise of the Mongol empire in a fun, fictional way.

Comment: how big a country are you looking it, as it is a quarter of the Mongolian population are his descendants. if his dynasty has persisted for just 1 or 2 more generations that might be enough.

Answer (score 1):

> There needs to be a way to encourage interbreeding in order to eventually replace the entire country with The Temujin's descendents. However, a simple reward system wouldn't work, as not every child can be given a government job or some high position.

After his transformation Yeshuah Targeryean genes contain no dominant or recessive genetic diseases, with every new generation of inbreeding there will be less genetic diseases, instead of more. But even more important is that the children of every generation of inbreeding live longer than the generation before them. This effect is accelerated if Yeshuah keeps breeding his offspring. So if you want healthy long lived children you better like those distant cousins of yours.

> There also needs to be a minimum amount of children that need to be born each generation for this to happen, taking into account random events such as wars, famine, etc.

Every family that sends their pretty daughters to Yeshuah for some more inbreeding get a tax cut, families that marry their children to other descendants of Yeshuah get a smaller tax cut. With every generation the children will live longer and have more children.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to do anything to encourage inbreeding. Inbreeding was a sufficiently common practice that admonitions to STOP doing it appear again and again in letters to early Christian churches in different nations around the Roman sphere of influence, and among the Israelites before that. It was a thing done by the gods themselves, as Augustine pointed out in his observations of the mixed traditional Roman worship and Christian Rome in 'City of God'.

There was a system of patronage in place throughout the latin-speaking world, as well as a tradition of grooming. Really, you need do very little more than encourage these practices

Comment: Some months ago I read an argument that the Church opposed cousin marriage as a way to weaken clans.  Now where was that …